DataTables.net version issue
In my current project, i'm using Symfony 7.1 with Webpack encore SF bundle.
I have Webpack 5.95.0.
I'm using Yarn 4.4.0 to manage my js package.
I'm using datatables.net 2.1.8.
After doing lot of test and debug, i finally notice that my project is using datatables.net 2.0.8 instead of 2.1.8.
It is a big deal because i want to use the option deferLoading which does not exist on 2.0.8 and has been reintroduce in 2.1.
I don't understand why an older version is used.
datatables.net-buttons-bs5 has dependency : datatables.net-bs5@npm:^2 BUT it still use : 2.0.8 (datatables.net-bs5@npm:^2 → npm:2.0.8)
For information datatables.net-bs5 is just to change some html code to fit bootstrap5
The ^2 should look for the last version of 2 and should be 2.1.8, no ?
Do i miss something or misunderstand something ?
At the end, i end up with 2 version of datatables.net-bs5 installed : 2.0.8 and 2.1.8 even if in the package.json it is only 2.1.8.
From the cache of yarn, i can see both of them.
I tried to clean the yarn cache and reinstall rebuild, nothing change.
My package.json :
    "datatables.net": "^2.1.8",
    "datatables.net-bs5": "^2.1.8",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs5": "^3.1.2",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-bs5": "^2.0.4",
    "datatables.net-plugins": "^2.1.7",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs5": "^3.0.3",

yarn info
├─ datatables.net-bs5@npm:2.1.8
│  ├─ Version: 2.1.8
│  │ 
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ datatables.net@npm:2.1.8 → npm:2.1.8
│     └─ jquery@npm:>=1.7 → npm:3.7.1
│
├─ datatables.net-buttons-bs5@npm:3.1.2
│  ├─ Version: 3.1.2
│  │ 
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ datatables.net-bs5@npm:^2 → npm:2.0.8
│     ├─ datatables.net-buttons@npm:3.1.2 → npm:3.1.2
│     └─ jquery@npm:>=1.7 → npm:3.7.1
│
├─ datatables.net-colreorder-bs5@npm:2.0.4
│  ├─ Version: 2.0.4
│  │ 
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ datatables.net-bs5@npm:^2 → npm:2.0.8
│     ├─ datatables.net-colreorder@npm:2.0.4 → npm:2.0.4
│     └─ jquery@npm:>=1.7 → npm:3.7.1
│
├─ datatables.net-plugins@npm:2.1.7
│  ├─ Version: 2.1.7
│  │ 
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ @types/jquery@npm:^3.5.16 → npm:3.5.30
│     └─ datatables.net@npm:^2.0.8 → npm:2.0.8
│
├─ datatables.net-responsive-bs5@npm:3.0.3
│  ├─ Version: 3.0.3
│  │ 
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ datatables.net-bs5@npm:^2 → npm:2.0.8
│     ├─ datatables.net-responsive@npm:3.0.3 → npm:3.0.3
│     └─ jquery@npm:>=1.7 → npm:3.7.1
│
├─ datatables.net@npm:2.1.8
│  ├─ Version: 2.1.8
│  │ 
│  └─ Dependencies
│     └─ jquery@npm:>=1.7 → npm:3.7.1
│


I finally managed to fix it.
I remove all package except the main datatables.net.
Then add one by one the rest.
This time, it end up to use the proper version 2.1.8 !
It is a bit strange though
